# BASH to python code translation: command recall and history

Tags: python, bash, code-translation

I have a BASH script that is the implementation of a pseudo-terminal. The entire script emulates logging in and running commands in an embedded operating system on another device.

Here is the function that presents the user with a prompt and accepts input:

```
function mterm
{
#   Interactive psuedo-terminal for sending commands to stbox.
#
#   An endless loop  prompts user for input.
#   The prompt displayed is the IP address of the target and '>'.
#   Commands consisting of pipes (|) and redirects (>) are parsed 
#   such that the first command is sent to "parsecommand" function,
#   and the output of that function is piped or redirected to the
#   remaining items on the command line which was entered by the
#   user at the prompt.
#
#   The commands entered by the user at the prompt are saved
#   in a "history" file defined by the HIST* variables below. The
#   user should be able to recall previous commands (and edit them
#   if desired) by using the arrow keys.
    export HISTFILE=~/.gsi_history
    export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
    export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
    export HISTSIZE=10000
    export HISTFILESIZE=100000

    history -r ${HISTFILE}

    while read -ep "${1}> " CMD
    do
        history -s "${CMD}"
        s="[|>]"
        if [[ ${CMD} =~ ${s} ]]
        then
            CMD1=${CMD%%[>|]*}
            CMD2=${CMD#${CMD1}}
            CMD1=$(echo ${CMD1}|xargs) # To remove any leading or training whitespaces.
            eval "parsecommand \"${CMD1}\"${CMD2}"
        else
            parsecommand "${CMD}"
        fi
    done

    history -w ${HISTFILE}
}
```

I am trying to do something similar in python. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "Exiting"
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

f=sys.stdin

while 1:
    print "> ",
    CMD=f.readline()
    if not CMD: break
    print("CMD: %s" % CMD)
```

This works. It accepts input commands and prints out what was typed in. So "CMD" can be passed to another function to parse it. If CTRL-D is typed, it ends, just like the BASH script.

However, like the BASH script, I would like a history file and command recall (using up-arrow, of course).

I suppose I could simply manually append "CMD" to a history file every time. Then I'd just need to worry about command recall.

Is there a nice and simple "pythonic" way to do what the BASH script does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/readline.html. Rolling your own probably isn't worth the effort.